# How to make the enter key move the cursor to the end of the line in Android Studio like it does in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

In Eclipse the enter key moves the cursor to the end of the line, then when you hit enter a second time it takes you to the next line. With Android Studio, however, you have to reach all the way over to the End key and then hit enter

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the default behavior of the Enter key should be to take you to the next line as its the most common and intuitive behavior.

However, you can see the currently assigned short cut for this behavior by going to the Preferences -> Key Map and then search "Move Caret to Line End". You can then also assign custom shortcut to make this happen.

Comment: Yeah but then Enter won't move to the next line when you hit Enter again